# Node app can not access local json file

Tags: json, node.js, d3.js, openshift

json file containing data and index.html in the Node app are in the same top directory. Using d3 js i am calling the json file to load data for visualization. But i am getting  http error 404 while loading the node app. Any suggestions?

Comment: your files are not populated via nodejs, you need to populate local files via some static handler

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and the pointer. Will give it a try.